# Showing that $a \mid b$ and $b \mid a$ if and only if $a= \pm b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a \mid b$ and $b \mid a$ if and only if $a= \pm b$.

How do I go about this proof? Step by step explanation please!

Comment: Have you gotten any progress on either direction (LHS implies RHS or RHS implies LHS)?

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $a \mid b$ if and only if there exists an integer $k$ such that $b = ak$.

Comment: Hint: First prove/observe that if $m,n$ are integers such that $mn=1$, then it must be the case that $m=n=\pm1$. Can you do that?

Comment: I did not downvote, but my guess for the downvotes is that no effort was shown towards a solution. The fear is that this is a homework question and then [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) applies.

Comment: My previous comment extends to the close votes.

Answer (score 5):

From $a|b$ we have $b=ka$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.
From $b|a$ we have $a=mb$ for some $m\in\mathbb Z$.
Hence $a=mb=mka$ and $a\cdot (1-mk)=0$, so $a=0$ or $mk=1$. If $a=0$, then also $b=ka=0$ and hence $b=a$. If on the other hand $mk=1$ then $k$ is a unit, hence $k=\pm1$ and $b=\pm a$.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that is valid. The other answers allow division by zero as written. Also, this is *exactly* what my answer was going to be.

Comment: Since it is erroneously thought that Bill's answer and my answer allow division by zero, I think I understand the downvotes there. Why the downvote here?

Comment: how do you know mb=mka ?

Comment: @Lil Since $b=ka$, you can just substitute into $mb$ and get $mka$.

Comment: after I do the algebra a/a=mka/a and get 1-mk=0 how do I know a=0, can't a also equal 1?

Comment: why is it a(1-mk)=0 instead of (1-mm)=0?

Comment: @Lil: "can't a also equal 1?": Since $a(1-mk)=0$, the answer was handled in two cases. First, $a=0$; then, $mk=1$. One of these two cases must be true.

Comment: @Lil: "(1-mm)=0?": $mk=1$ is one of the cases that we can assume from $a(1-mk)=0$. Where do you get $1-m^2=0$? Certainly, it can be deduced after getting $m=\pm1$, but not before.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ n = \dfrac{b}a\,$ and $\, \dfrac{1}n =\dfrac{a}b\,$ both integers $\iff n = \,\ldots$

Comment: As written, this allows division by zero.

Comment: @MPW: as Asaf commented on my answer, if $\frac ab$ and $\frac ba$ are both integers, neither $a$ nor $b$ can be $0$.

Comment: @MPW First, as emphasized at the start, it is a **hint**. By (careful) design, my hints focus on the essence of the matter. In particular, as here, they usually omit any mention of trivial exceptional cases such as $a$ or $b=0$ here. Second, the hint does not "allow division by zero" since then both terms are not integers. If this was the reason for the downvote(s), then I think it would be more constructive to simply add a comment such as "Note to OP: be sure to consider exceptional cases (purposely) omitted in the hint". Else the downvotes may scare students away from perfectly fine answers.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I was going to make the same comment about hints not being complete answers, but I didn't since I figured explaining why division by $0$ was not a problem would be enough. Perhaps not. There is also the possibility that MPW is not the downvoter; note that Hagen's answer was also downvoted and MPW upvoted his answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Sorry if I offended, will be more judicious in use of downvotes in the future. And your note regarding potential incompleteness of "hints" is acknowledged. Ditto to robjohn. (But you should encourage inexperienced math students to always be thinking of the possible exceptions to every single statement they write, right? After all, that's how you end up proving $0=1$ ...).

Comment: @MPW No problem. Thanks for explaining your viewpoint. Generally it is understood that hints leave some (usually minor) details to the reader - esp. trivialities that may  serve to obfuscate the main ideas of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose that $p=\frac ab\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q=\frac ba\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then you have
$$
pq=\frac ab\frac ba=1
$$
What factors does $1$ have?

Comment: As written, this allows division by zero.

Comment: @MPW: Not true. If $a=0$ then $\frac ba$ is not defined, and certainly not an element of $\Bbb Z$.