# Proof: If $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$, then $a\mid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proof: If $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$, then $a\mid c$

Can you tell me if my proof is correct?? If not what is wrong-step by step explanation please!

$b/a = l$ ($l$ is an integer)

$c/b = e$ ($e$ is an integer)

therefore:

$c/a = be\cdot l/b = el$ ($el$ is an integer)

Comment: Fine, except that “$a|b$” is not equivalent to “$b/a$ is an integer”, since after all it’s a true statement that 
$0|0$.

Comment: It is essentially correct. In elementary number theory, I prefer arguments that do not involve "fractions." So I would prefer to say that there is an integer $l$ such that $b=al$, and there is an integer $e$ such that $c=eb$, and therefore $c=eb=e(la)=(el)a$, and therefore $a$ divides $c$. This is "the same" proof as yours. The reason I prefer this version is that in elementary number theory courses, I have seen students get into difficulties by fraction manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

There is one (fairly substantial) problem with your proof approach. Note (for example) that $2\mid 0$ and $0\mid 0$ (so $0\mid 0$), but your proof approach would have us dividing by $0$, which we cannot do! However, it is easily fixable.

Instead, use the same sort of approach suggested in [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662258/showing-that-a-mid-b-and-b-mid-a-if-and-only-if-a-pm-b). Since $a\mid b,$ then $b=al$ for some integer $l.$ Since $b\mid c,$ then $c=be$ for some integer $e.$ As you noted, $el$ is also an integer, so since $$c=be=(al)e=a(le)=a(el),$$ then $a\mid c,$ as desired. In this way we avoid any potential division by $0.$

Comment: I see what you are saying but how did you get this part: =a(le)=a(el),

Comment: Which part exactly is throwing you? Is it $(al)e=a(le),$ or is it $a(le)=a(el)$? Both?

Comment: both of those final two.

Comment: Well, what do you know about $el$ and $le$ if $l$ and $e$ are integers? How are they related?

Comment: is my reasoning correct? c=be (given through proof step 1) be=al(e) because b=al and we need to multiply by e to keep it equal right? after this step I am lost though..

Comment: el and le are equivalent since multiplication is commutative

Comment: so you just regrouped them to prove the statement is true?

Comment: Precisely! Since $le=el,$ then $a(le)=a(el).$ Likewise, you're correct that since $b=al,$ then $be=(al)e.$

Comment: sorry for the extended comments- but thank you sooo much!!

Comment: As for the other equality, remember that multiplication is *associative*. Also, we can get there in fewer steps if we note that $le$ is an integer, and so $c=be=(al)e=a(le),$ at which point we're done.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a | b$ then can find $n$ integer such that $an = b$. Similarly, can find $k$ integer such that $bk = c$. Substituting, we obtain $$an = \frac{c}{k} \implies a (nk) = c \implies a \mid c $$

Comment: Not quite... you should be careful using $k$ as a denominator since it could be equal to zero. But $ank = bk = c$ does the job.